# How can I return an AJAX-retrieved value to the parent function of the current function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following JavaScript (and jQuery) code:

```
function checkEmail(email) {
    if (email.length) {
        $.getJSON('ajax/validate', {email: email}, function(data){
            if (data == false) {
                // stuff
            }
            return data;
        })
    }
}
```

I want the anonymous function to `return data` to the parent function, `checkEmail()`.  I tried doing something like this:

```
function checkEmail(email) {
    if (email.length) {
        var ret = null;
        $.getJSON('ajax/validate', {email: email}, function(data){
            if (data == false) {
                // stuff
            }
            ret = data;
        })
        return ret;
    }
}
```

But of course this won't work because the `$.getJSON()` call is asynchronous, so it will `return ret` before the GET request is finished.

Any thoughts here?

Thank you!

Comment: I see this same problem posted on here many times a day.  Don't start writing AJAX until you understand how it works, people!!

Comment: And then people vote this queston up instead of closing it as duplicate like they're supposed to.

Comment: FWIW, this is being closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094716/how-does-one-return-data-to-the-original-caller-function-in-javascript , which asks pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, the best way to handle this type of issue is to use some form of callback function.  Actually, it is really the only practicable solution -- the only other option is coding your own extensions to the browser, and that is a little much (unless you really like banging your head against a wall).  There are actually quite a few parallel questions on these boards: you might try searching for some, many are very good.

Modifying your code:

```
function checkEmail(email) {
    /*
        original parts of the function here!
    */

    if (email.length) {
        $.getJSON('ajax/validate', {email: email}, function(data){
            if (data == false) {
                // stuff
            }
            checkEmailResponse( data );
        })
    }
}

function checkEmailResponse( data )
{
    // do something with the data.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should as well use a callback because the call is asynchronous and therefore design you whole JavaScript source around that idea (as the others pointed out).

If you really really need to get it as a return value you need to turn the asynchronous call off but this is not recommended at all, because it blocks the page till the response is there.

```
function checkEmail(email, callback) {
    if (email.length) 
    return $.ajax({
      data:  {email: email},
      url: 'ajax/validate',
      async: false
     }).responseText; // only the raw response text of the XMLHttpRequest
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the parent function block until there is something there.  And to reduce the CPU intensiveness, you could use a timeout of somekind.

```
function checkEmail(email) {
if (email.length) {
    var ret = null;
    $.getJSON('ajax/validate', {email: email}, function(data){
        if (data == false) {
            // stuff
        }
        ret = data;
    }) 
   while(ret == null){

   }
   return ret;
}
```

}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to change the way you approach the problem.  You know that what you have above won't work, so you can't think in terms of "call a function and operate on its return value".

You'll need to switch to something like toby's suggestion of CPS, or depending on what's triggering this function, handling it with custom events.